# C - Change all values of an array of structures in one line

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, structure

I can declare a structure:

```
typedef struct
{
  int var1;
  int var2;
  int var3;
} test_t;
```

Then create an array of those structs structure with default values:

```
test_t theTest[2] =
{
   {1,2,3},
   {4,5,6}
};
```

But after I've created the array, is there any way to change the values in the same way I did above, using only one line, specifying every value explicitly without a loop?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C99 you can assign each structure in a single line.  I don't think that you can assign the array of structs in one line though.

C99 introduces compound literals.  See the Dr. Dobbs article here:  [The New C:  Compound Literals](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184401404)

```
theTest[0] = (test_t){7,8,9};
theTest[1] = (test_t){10,11,12};
```

You could assign to a pointer like this:

```
test_t* p; 
p = (test_t [2]){ {7,8,9}, {10,11,12} };
```

You could use memcpy as well:

```
memcpy(theTest, (test_t [2]){ {7,8,9}, {10,11,12} }, sizeof(test_t [2]);
```

Above tested with **gcc -std=c99** (version 4.2.4) on linux.

You should read the Dr. Dobbs article to understand how compound literals work.

Comment: With that, you could create a macro for a assignment loop. That way, it's easy to reuse and very clean.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to set the values to zero (or -1), you can use `memset`:

```
memset(struct_array, 0, sizeof(struct_array));
memset(struct_array, -1, sizeof(struct_array));
```

Comment: True, but not very complete.  You have forgotten about C99.

Comment: I just mentioned this as an alternative method for a common particular case of the problem. I didn't claim it solves the complete problem.

Answer (score 0):

i think no, you can only init arrays by this way.
but you can change values of structures using 'one-line' method

Comment: Did you mean 'cannot change values'?  See also the answer mentioning C99.

Comment: sorry, i use only -c99 and didn`t mention that. i often use this feature: "theTest[0] = (test_t){7,8,9};"

Answer (score 0):

If the variables are being copied from another source, you can use a method like memcpy to directly overwrite the struct values.

However, the language doesn't provide a direct way to just set the values, other than setting individual elements.