# C++: assign two values to char** in one line?

Tags: c++

I try to assign two c-strings at once:

```
 char **pair = {"name","joe"};
```

but I get error message:

```
 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char [5]' to 'char **'
```

But I think something like that worked for me before?

Comment: Is this C or C++? With gcc 4.7.2, try  `char *pair[] = {"name","joe"};`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple C array declaration / assignment question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582165/simple-c-array-declaration-assignment-question)

Comment: Also, visit http://c-faq.com and read about pointers. **They are not arrays.** And arrays aren't pointers either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joachim approach creates read-only string. That's how you create an array of const string literals.

Another way,

```
// MAX_LEN being the max string length.
char pair[][MAX_LEN] = {"name","joe"}; // This makes pair read-writeable,
```

Answer (score 8):

You declare a pointer-to-pointer but the initializer is an *array* of pointers:

```
const char *pair[] = { "name", "joe" };
```

---

As noted I added the `const` keyword to the declaration. This is because the pointers are pointers to string literals, and literals are constant and can't be changed. Adding that `const` helps the programmer not to make changes by mistake to the strings in the array.

Comment: +1 for also noting use of `const`.  Would it be worth explaining this in the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Use C++ facilities, it will save you a world of pain:

```
vector<string> field = { "name", "joe" };
```

Although maybe you need:

```
pair<string, string> field("name", "joe");
```

Or better yet, possibly:

```
struct Person {
    Person(const string& name) : name(name) {}
    const string name;
};

Person boss("joe");
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers given here are correct. What to choose depends on context:

1. If you never changes the strings at *runtime*, go for Joachim Pileborg's approach
2. If you for some reason know that strings have a fixed length, go for Arun's
3. If neither 1 or 2, go for Peter Wood's. Note that

   ```
   vector<string> field = { "name", "joe" };
   ```

   requires C++11

Answer (score 0):

const char *pair[] = { "name", "joe"  };

This is the best solution